# How to better organize a class with a lot of fields?

Tags: oop

I am currently implementing something similar to an hospital intra site, where doctors can see info about their patients.

Currently, I have a LOT of info regarding each Client: his full name, date of birth, blood type, where he lives, diseases he had, etc.

My first attempt was something of the form:

```
class Client {
    private string fullName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    ...

    public Get/Set FullName()
    public Get/Set DateOfBirth()
    ...
}
```

which is basically putting everything together under the same class.

After a while I decided that maybe I should pack together similar concepts into a more general one. For example, I can encapsulate both `userName` and `password` into the same concept -- `LoginInfo`, for example.

1. If doing this, should I provide all the getters/setters  on the Client class that delegate the work to the correct inner concepts, or should I just put getters for the concepts themselves? The first approach would shield the outside world to the Client class implementation,  but then maybe, we wouldn't win that much by having all these innner concepts.
2. Should code outside the `Client` class even know the different kinds of concepts that'd use inside it?
3. Any other idea / approach?

I still don't know much about what methods I'll need to have on the `Client` class. Maybe if there are a lot, it'd be definetely good idea to use small inner concepts to group similar methods in themselves, instead of having such a loose coupled big class.

The data of `Client` will all be persisted using a standard database, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is useful to pack related pieces of data into common classes. I would only provide delegating getters/setters in `Client` for very commonly used properties though (if even then - it should be a case by case decision). If a concept makes sense in the problem domain, it is fine to expose it to the outside world too. Your `LoginInfo` is a marginal detail in this regard, but disease history, health check results etc. etc. are prime candidates for this.

I would also recommend you check out Martin Fowler's excellent [Analysis Patterns](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4V8pZmpwmBYC&dq=analysis+patterns&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=_cKlTI-HHIOLswb29vGaCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false), which dedicates a chapter to health care patterns; you may probably get some useful ideas out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider when deciding how to organize data: are there any requirements for tracking history of data.  For example, do you need to know what the patient's address was 5 years ago (in addition to knowing their current address, of course)?  If so, making that "historically-sensitive" data its own class, will likely make it easier for you down the road.  Of course, some data won't be "historically-sensitive" - date of birth for example.  :)

Something else to consider: what data will be shared among patients?  If you maintain data about family medical history, should that data be shared among siblings?  If so, then encapsulating that data in its own object will save you lots of copy/synchronization pain later.

These aren't the only considerations when analyzing your data.  But they're definitely part of the puzzle.